# Command ValidateEmbeddedBinary failed with a nonzero exit code error while running on iPhone 13

Tags: swift, flutter, xcode, dart

I am getting this annoying message whenever I try to run ios build on my iPhone 13.

I am using M1 2020

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS3q3.png)

I try the all available solution posted on like "uncheck rosetta, Build Active Architecture only"

is there something I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

**Run flutter doctor -v**

**Flutter clean**

**Pub get**

if possible restart your MacBook because most of the time Xcode needs to restart to adopt new changes

Comment: it works (restarting Macbook helped to fix it)